# Modelagem Fluent API com tabela de referência

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fluent-api

Gostaria de saber como realizo a modelagem de uma determinada entidade, onde seu valor de referência pertence a outra tabela. Esse valor de referência seria uma tabela de domínio que possui seus id´s referentes aos cartões de crédito, pois meu usuário poderá cadastrar que seu atendimento aceita várias bandeiras de cartão de crédito do tipo Visa, Master, etc.

Abaixo segue um exemplo das minhas entidades:

```
public class CartaoCreditoUsuario 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int CartaoCreditoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario.Usuario Usuario { get; set; }        
}

public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Enderecos = new List<Endereco>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ConfirmaçãoEmail{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartaoCreditoUsuario> CartaoCreditoUsuario { get; set; }
       ....

}

public class CartaoCredito
{
    public int CartaoCreditoId { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoCartaoCredito { get; set; }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como ficaria meu `modelBuilder.Configurations` referente às entidades citadas acima.

Desde já agradeço antecipadamente.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi o que você quer, fica assim:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>() 
    .HasMany(t => t.CartoesCredito) 
    .WithMany(t => t.Usuarios) 
    .Map(m => 
    { 
        m.ToTable("CartoesCreditoUsuarios"); 
        m.MapLeftKey("Id"); 
        m.MapRightKey("CartaoCreditoId"); 
    });
```

Neste caso, as entidades ficam assim:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Enderecos = new List<Endereco>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ConfirmaçãoEmail{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartaoCredito> CartoesCredito { get; set; }
       ....

}

public class CartaoCredito
{
    public int CartaoCreditoId { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoCartaoCredito { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }    
}
```

Note que, como a Fluent API controla tudo, você não tem controle sobre a entidade associativa. Para mapear manualmente, você terá que abrir mão da Fluent API e mapear da seguinte forma:

```
public class CartaoCreditoUsuario 
{
    public int CartaoCreditoUsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public int CartaoCreditoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual CartaoCredito CartaoCredito { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{    
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ConfirmacaoEmail{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CartaoCreditoUsuario> CartoesCreditoUsuario { get; set; }
       ....

}

public class CartaoCredito
{
    public int CartaoCreditoId { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoCartaoCredito { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CartaoCreditoUsuario> UsuariosCartaoCredito { get; set; }

}
```

Não é preciso mais do que a simples declaração de classes para funcionar.